# Key error '0' with dict format

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, format, keyerror

I'm still a beginner in Python, and I wanted to know why this :

```
    dict = {}
    dict[0] = '123'
    a = 0
    if dict["{}".format(a)]["{}".format(a)] == '1':
        print('True')
```

gives me a Key Error '0' but not this :

```
    dict = {}
    dict[0] = '123'
    if dict[0][0] == '1':
       print('True')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to compare the key `0` with `"0"`. They are different. One is an integer and one is a string.

Comment: and one more thing, you are now effectively hiding the definition of the type dict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to compare the key 0 with "0". They are different. One is an integer and another is a string.